# Save Cookies in Gomez test

Tags: cookies, performance-testing

Is there a way to keep cookies and run a 'subsequent' view in a test? I am trying to confirm performance boost from a cookie-based feature, and need to be able to have Gomez re-load a page a second time and keep the cookie from the first. As far as I can tell each page view is a separate test, and it clears cookies each test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question, now that StackOverflow has given the "tumbleweed" badge (ha)... This can be done through the UI with two steps. Add the HTTP Cookies in the Recorder tool, and in the test settings set to "Cache Content".

Unfortunately I don't have screenshots to show this setup, since we ended up not going with Gomez as a solution.